# What does "source population" mean?

Tags: terminology

> Vietnamese are associated with the “source population” 
>   that ultimately was responsible for the modern Vietnamese, Thai people and Lao people.

What does "source population" in the sentence mean? Ancestor?

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am not sure of this answer as it is me vaguely remembering things from highschool.

I *think* a "source population" in this case is alluding to the original population originating from the original local bloodlines eliminating the immigrants and the "impure" inhabitants from the set.

Think of it as the descendants of the original settlers of the area, in this case - Vietnam.

I am drawing this from somewhere around the 19th century Quebec when "Source Canadians" would distinguish themselves from newcomers despite having the exact same origin. The sole different being that the former has lived there for generations and their ancestors where the ones who colonized the territory in the first place.

More than anything, it's to draw the difference between *nationality* and *citizenship* both of which would make you Vietnamese but where only the first one would qualify you as a "source Vietnamese"

Hopefully I am right. Otherwise I may be dead wrong.

Comment: I think I am asking " source population" who "were" responsible for modern people. However, you answered " modern population" who are responsible for ancient people.

Comment: @Jun Well it doesn't really change anything. In that case it is referring to the people who were at the time the source population. They were the modern population back then.